# How to extract the value of a global variable from a compiled C program?

Tags: c, gcc, keil

There is a project which builds by Keil, there is an array in the code like the following:

```
#define A_NUMBER 3

int i = 0;
int intToBeRead[5] = {
    0x01,
    2,
    A_NUMBER,
    sizeof(i),
#ifdef SHOULD_BE_FIVE
    5
#else
    6
#endif
};

int main(void) {

}
```

The objective is to capture the initial values of the array `intToBeRead`, is there a way to capture the values without rewriting a preprocessor from the source code, or is there a way to capture the values from the compiled files?

i.e. Through the use of another tool, the initial value of the array can be stored in a text file, which has nothing to do with the source code.

Edit: I am working with a legacy repository with c source code, there is a list of values (changes in different versions) stored in an int array that requires to be captured/exported, which can then be processed (put the lists of arrays into an excel file or database) outside of the c source code. The flow of the information is from source code to a external (text) file, due to lack of early planning of the process.

Comment: explain what you mean by "capture the values" ?

Comment: The question is unclear.  You have an array initialized to 5 _predetermined_  `int` values, then an infinite loop `while(1).  What do you expect this to do?

Comment: @M.M I would like to capture the values of {1,2,3,4,6} then put them in a text file.

Comment: @ryyker I would like to capture the 5 predetermined values for other uses, which will be outside of the c source code. The while loop has nothing to do with this question really, so I took it out.

Comment: Are you talking about at runtime or compile time?

Comment: Are you speaking of something like an initialization file, i.e. to be read at run-time to initialize variables or other run-time behavior ???

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"? What does it mean to "capture a value"? You want to "capture a value" when running the program or without running the program? From "where" should the values be "captured"?

Comment: "I would like to capture the values of {1,2,3,4,6} then put them in a text file." Is the reverse an option? I.e. have the five valus in a text file and use them from there in the code? With some assumptions and restrictions that would be possible at compile time.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have updated the question regarding what capture means. The exctraction of the int array should not involve running the actual compiled programmer, I am looking for a way to either get the list of value directly from the source code, or from the compiled files, if possible. Thanks

Comment: @Yunnosch unfortunately, the flow of the information is from source code to the text file, due to lack of early planning of the process.

Comment: Can you get it from the map file? Those should be in the .data section to put into bss.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. Looking at the (quite cool) examples for values, it was kind of implied. But I thought to ask and double check, sometimes this opens up new ideas.

Comment: Have you tried with gdb? It can usually show you the contents of global variables even if the program is not running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use utilities such as objdump to see what's in the executable.  For example, on your code compiled to a file called x1, this command:

```
objdump -d -j .data x1
```

shows the .data section which contains the variable:

```
x1:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000601030 <__data_start>:
    ...

0000000000601040 <intToBeRead>:
  601040:   01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00     ................
  601050:   06 00 00 00                                         ....
```

From here, you can see that the values (assuming little-endian) are 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6.